# Any suggestion on how to override Chart JS Donut library

Tags: javascript

I have added a donut chart as shown below without the numbers.

I wanted to make the outer-border fixed like the first picture shown below and hide the inner border and I have used Chart JS.

Any way I can do that as the chart JS default there is only border-color?

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('freeChart');

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      data: [30,70],
      backgroundColor: ['#9f9fa6'],
      borderColor: ['#9f9fa6','#9f9fa6'],
    }],
  },
  options:{
    cutoutPercentage: 80,
    elements: {
      arc: {
        borderWidth: 1
      }
    }
  }
});
```

[image: outer border fixed]

[image]

Comment: borderColor is an array, try to pass it one element `borderColor: ['#9f9fa6']`

Comment: the border colour array is linked to the data so 30% will display with the first border colour, 70% will display with another inputted border color,